# Getting error in implementing list view with images in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, constructor

I am beginner in android.I am trying to make listview with image in fragment.But its not getting done.
Here my code is

**ListoneFragment.java:**(here name1 and name2 are string array names in my **strings.xml** file)

```
package fragments.h.safmical;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import safmical.h.R;

/**
 * Created by hadvani on 4/14/2017.
 */

public class ListOneFragment extends Fragment {
    String[] titles;
    String[] shortforms;
    int[] images={R.drawable.hcll,R.drawable.hno,R.drawable.hcll,R.drawable.hno,R.drawable.hcll,R.drawable.hno};
    ListView listView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listone, container, false);
        Resources res =getResources();
        titles=res.getStringArray(R.array.name1);
        shortforms=res.getStringArray(R.array.name2);
        listView = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.list1);

       MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(this,titles,images,shortforms);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootview;
    }
}
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
Context context;
    int[] images;
    String[] titleArray;
    String[] shortformArray;
    MyAdapter(Context c,String[] titles,int imgs[],String[] shortform){
     super(c,R.layout.fragment_listpattern,R.id.textView1,titles);
        this.context=c;
        this.images=imgs;
        this.titleArray=titles;
        this.shortformArray=shortform;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listpattern,parent,false);

        ImageView myImage=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        TextView myTitle=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView myShortform=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
        myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
        myShortform.setText(shortformArray[position]);

        return row;
    }
}
```

here my xml file

**fragment_listone.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list1">

</ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_listpattern.xml:**(for pattern of single row of list view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:text="TextView" />


</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

When i am running it.It shows **error**:

```
Error:(37, 40) error: incompatible types: ListOneFragment cannot be converted to Context
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

And it shows suggestion in **ListoneFragment.java** in line
**MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(this,titles,images,shortforms);** in parameters
that 
                 **change 1st parameter of method 'MyAdapter' from Context to 'ListoneFragment'**.

And When i do that it makes errors in MyAdapter class's constructer.
**What should i do,is there any correction or is there other way  to implement this.Please help?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use activity `context` to initialize the adapter class:

in your `ListOneFragment` use:

```
MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(getActivity(), titles, images,shortforms);
```

Comment: Thanks man.it worked.But can you tell me why previously written "this" as a parameter not worked?

Comment: Fragments are a part of activity ...so for context inside adapter you need to pass the activity context:  `getActivity()` and `this` keyword is used in your activity for passing context . so it will not work inside your fragment class